# Duplicate cookie with same name creates undesired behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to save browser state by storing it into a cookie.For some reason this does not seem to always work how I want it because it creates a duplicate cookie with the same name.Here is what I mean:

[image]

This is the only code I am using to work with cookies:

```
$(function () {
var content = $("#content");
var state = $.cookie("layoutState");

if (state === "grid") {
    content.removeClass("content-list").addClass("content-grid");
}

if (state === "list") {
    content.removeClass("content-grid").addClass("content-list");
}

$("#list").on("click", function (e) {
    $.cookie("layoutState", "list", { expires: 7, path: "/" });
    content.removeClass("content-grid").addClass("content-list");
    e.preventDefault();
})

$("#grid").on("click", function (e) {
    $.cookie("layoutState", "grid", { expires: 7, path: "/"});
    content.removeClass("content-list").addClass("content-grid");
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

})

I am using jQuery cookie plugin.

Does anyone understand what the problem is I have been trying to solve it for hours with no luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check if cookie exist, delete and create one, like:

```
if( $.cookie("layoutState") ) {
   $.removeCookie('layoutState', { path: '/' });
}
//and create
$.cookie("layoutState", "grid", { expires: 7, path: "/"});
```